# Boost 1.56 linking error + warning

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I installed the new boost 1.56 beta. when i build my programms i get following warnings

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_regex.so.1.56.0, needed by /opt/boost/lib/libboost_log.so, may conflict with libboost_regex.so.1.46.1
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_regex.so.1.56.0, needed by /opt/boost/lib/libboost_log.so, may conflict with libboost_regex.so.1.46.1
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_filesystem.so.1.56.0, needed by /opt/boost/lib/libboost_log.so, may conflict with libboost_filesystem.so.1.46.1
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_filesystem.so.1.56.0, needed by /opt/boost/lib/libboost_log.so, may conflict with libboost_filesystem.so.1.46.1
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_filesystem.so.1.56.0, needed by /opt/boost/lib/libboost_log.so, may conflict with libboost_filesystem.so.1.46.1
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_date_time.so.1.56.0, needed by /opt/boost/lib/libboost_log.so, may conflict with libboost_date_time.so.1.46.1
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_date_time.so.1.56.0, needed by /opt/boost/lib/libboost_log.so, may conflict with libboost_date_time.so.1.46.1
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_thread.so.1.56.0, needed by /opt/boost/lib/libboost_log.so, may conflict with libboost_thread.so.1.46.1
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_thread.so.1.56.0, needed by /opt/boost/lib/libboost_log.so, may conflict with libboost_thread.so.1.46.1
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_thread.so.1.56.0, needed by /opt/boost/lib/libboost_log.so, may conflict with libboost_thread.so.1.46.1
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_system.so.1.56.0, needed by /opt/boost/lib/libboost_log.so, may conflict with libboost_system.so.1.46.1
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_system.so.1.56.0, needed by /opt/boost/lib/libboost_log.so, may conflict with libboost_system.so.1.46.1
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_regex.so.1.56.0, needed by /opt/boost/lib/libboost_log.so, may conflict with libboost_regex.so.1.46.1
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_regex.so.1.56.0, needed by /opt/boost/lib/libboost_log.so, may conflict with libboost_regex.so.1.46.1
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_filesystem.so.1.56.0, needed by /opt/boost/lib/libboost_log.so, may conflict with libboost_filesystem.so.1.46.1
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_filesystem.so.1.56.0, needed by /opt/boost/lib/libboost_log.so, may conflict with libboost_filesystem.so.1.46.1
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_filesystem.so.1.56.0, needed by /opt/boost/lib/libboost_log.so, may conflict with libboost_filesystem.so.1.46.1
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/mapconverter.dir/src/mapconverter.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN5boost10filesystem6detail28directory_iterator_constructERNS0_18directory_iteratorERKNS0_4pathEPNS_6system10error_codeE'
/usr/bin/ld: note: '_ZN5boost10filesystem6detail28directory_iterator_constructERNS0_18directory_iteratorERKNS0_4pathEPNS_6system10error_codeE' is defined in DSO /opt/boost/lib/libboost_filesystem.so.1.56.0 so try adding it to the linker command line
/opt/boost/lib/libboost_filesystem.so.1.56.0: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: Fehler: ld gab 1 als Ende-Status zurück
```

anyone has an idea how i can remove this warnings? I use cmake with defined BOOST_ROOT and defined Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS ON . But i still get this error

Edit: Now get get additionally a linking error ...

Comment: it looks like you have 2 version of boost installed.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the old version?

Comment: yes i have but with Boost_No_System_Path it should not use my system boost or? I 'm compiling my programm with c++11 and boost normal could this be a problem ?

Comment: 1.56.0? damn should I re-upgrade boost again?

Comment: with 1.55 i get only the warnings but when i change back to boost 1.55 i get no the same error... but before that it works well... i dont understand it

Comment: Which CMake version are you using? Have you tried setting `Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS` (should not be necessary if you're already on CMake 3)?

Comment: i am on cmake 2.8.7 so an update is usefull or ? Butt not sure if this is possible because i use it with ROS packages